# How to use multiple forms in same React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, mern

I want to make a multi-stage react form. In this particular code, only Zipcode will be asked and will be submitted on submitting the form. But how to bring other forms asking for Email, important thing~ I want the form for email after I submit Zipcode, as both email and zipcode will be sent to backend together.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const  Rider_Signup = ()=>{
 const [zipcode,setzipcode]=useState();
 const [email,set_email]=useState();
 const onSubmitform = async e =>{
     e.preventDefault();
     try{
         const body={zipcode,email};
         const response = await fetch("https://taxibackendf.herokuapp.com/api/service/signup",{
             method:"POST",headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
             body:JSON.stringify(body)
         })
         const datainjson = await response.json();
         window.location =`/driver/login`;
     }catch(err){
         console.log('Error')
     }
 }
 return (   
  <div className="admin_form_div">
    

    <form  action="/initial" id="admin_form"  name="admin_form" onSubmit={onSubmitform}
            <input type="text" name="Zipcode" className="input" value={zipcode} 
             onChange={e =>setzipcode(e.target.value)} 
               />  
            <button type="submit" className="confirm_btn" >Confirm</button>
    </form> 
 </div>
 );
  };
   export default Rider_Signup;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [step, setstep] = useState(1);

const [formdata, setFormData] = useState({zip:"", email:""}); // use to hold input from user 

const renderForm = () =>{
    switch(step){
        case 1: return <div>Form one with email<button onClick = {() => setstep(step+1)}>Submit</button></div>
        case 2: return <div>Form with zip code <button onClick = {() => setstep(step+1)}>Submit</button></div>
        default: return <div>Default case</div>


    }

}
return (

    renderForm()
)
```

`

Comment: A newbie question for verification ~     <input type="email" name="name" className="Email" value={formdata.email} onChange={e =>setFormData(formdata.email=(e.target.value))}" required />                                                               will this be correct format?

Comment: <input type="email" name="name" className="Email" value={formdata.email} onChange={e =>setFormData({...formdata, email:e.target.value})}" required />